# Google maps create marker with geolocations

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-maps, geolocation, geocoding

Using react i'm trying to create a google maps with markers, that apply to an address instead of lat/lng values. As you can see the component creates a script tag when mounted and initializes map and marker through the google.maps... functions. If i create a marker with lat/lng it works fine, but instead i want to search by address. So here's my code, can you find the bug? 
I'm not using any packages and would also like to stick to that. (NO PACKAGES!)
Another question would be in what format i have to write those addresses. Street, Postalcode, city?

Stack overflow wants some more text so sorry for repeating myself.

```
export interface ProjectsListMapProps {
}

export default class ProjectsListMap extends React.Component<ProjectsListMapProps> {
  constructor(props: ProjectsListMapProps) {
    super(props);
    this.renderMap = this.renderMap.bind(this);
    this.mapContainer = this.mapContainer.bind(this); 
    this.codeAddress = this.codeAddress.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (!document.querySelectorAll(`[src="${'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY'}"]`).length) { 
      document.body.appendChild(Object.assign(
        document.createElement('script'), {
          type: 'text/javascript',
          src: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js',
          onload: () => this.renderMap()
        }
      ));
    }
  }

  renderMap() {
    const coords = { lat: 41.375885, lng: 2.177813 };
    const el = document.getElementById('map');
    if (el) {
      const map = new google.maps.Map(el, {
        zoom: 16,
        center: {
          lat: coords.lat,
          lng: coords.lng
        }
      });
      const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      this.codeAddress(geocoder, map);
      return map;
    }
    else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  codeAddress(geocoder: any, map: any) {
    geocoder.geocode({'address': 'Budapest'}, function(results: any, status: any) {
      console.log(results);

      if (status === 'OK') {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
        return marker;
      } 
      else {
        return null;
      }
    });
  } 

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="card map-holder">
        <div id="map" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My Log returns an empty array as a result.

Check out: https://codepen.io/mblmarlon/pen/PoqzjXy for an example

Comment: Can you provide a working [mcve] as a code snippet / fiddle?

Comment: I've removed your API key from your question. Please don't share private API keys on public sites, and make sure you restrict them as per https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey

Comment: @evan if it is properly restricted then you can share it anywhere you like... it's public anyway on any website using the API.

Comment: @MrUpsidown https://codepen.io/mblmarlon/pen/PoqzjXy sorry took me a bit

Comment: I get an error when running your code: *Geocoding Service: This API project is not authorized to use this API.  For more information on authentication and Google Maps JavaScript API services please see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key* - did you not see it? I think it speaks for itself...

Comment: @MrUpsidown I saw it but since themap was working i just ignored it. However, does this mean that i need another api call just for the geolocation stuff?

Comment: No, you need to enable the Geocoding API in your [developers console](https://console.developers.google.com/). You should read the link that comes with the error message, it's actually useful.

Comment: Yeah, got it yesterday. Thx for your help @MrUpsidown

Comment: @MrUpsidown sorry for the delayed reply! just answered you here. :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60611155/this-code-is-not-fetching-lat-long-for-all-values-if-any-one-has-better-approac#comment107249048_60611155

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like your code is using Google Maps JavaScript Geocoding service and not Geolocation.

Upon checking it seems that Geocoding service is working properly now however you are still hardcoding the value of your address in the code. To help you further, I tweak your code and added text input field for your address. Here is the [sample code](https://codepen.io/devpage/pen/mdJrZZp).

```
var map;
class BookSlider extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.renderMap = this.renderMap.bind(this);
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      input: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // ADD API KEY HERE
    if (
      !document.querySelectorAll(
        `[src="${"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY"}"]`
      ).length
    ) {
      document.body.appendChild(
        Object.assign(document.createElement("script"), {
          type: "text/javascript",
          // ADD API KEY HERE
          src:
            "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY",
          onload: () => this.renderMap()
        })
      );
    }
  }

  renderMap() {
    const coords = { lat: 41.375885, lng: 2.177813 };
    const el = document.getElementById("map");

    if (el) {
      map = new google.maps.Map(el, {
        zoom: 16,
        center: {
          lat: coords.lat,
          lng: coords.lng
        }
      });

      return map;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === "checkbox" ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  handleClick(event) {
    const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    this.codeAddress(geocoder);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  // THIS CRASHES if you comment it out //

  codeAddress(geocoder) {
    var address = this.state.input;
    geocoder.geocode({ address: address }, function(results, status) {
      console.log(results);
      if (status === "OK") {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
        return marker;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section className="partial-book-slider">
        <h1>ADD YOUR API KEY TO MAKE IT WORKIN</h1>
        <input
          id="input"
          name="input"
          value={this.state.input}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
        <button id="submit" onClick={this.handleClick}>
          {" "}
          Search
        </button>

        <div className="card map-holder">
          <div id="map" />
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
/*
 * Render the above component into the div#app
 */
React.render(<BookSlider />, document.getElementById("app"));
```